# Using delegates and events with DI in a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, delegates

I have a system which fundamentally is used to resolve exceptions and output a CSV **on demand** which details every resolved item. Each day, there will be new exceptions which need to be dealt with. I have a `POST` method for this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
private ActionResult Resolve(ExceptionViewModel modifiedExceptionViewModel, string currentFilter)
{
      // resolve database records...

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Exceptions");
}
```

I have had a new requirement however, the user wants the system to identify when the last outstanding has been resolved and then automatically output the CSV to the file share, rather than having to go and do this manually.

I firstly created a method for checking whether or not that was the last exception, and called this `WasLastException();` I knew that I could just wrap this in an IF statement and on true call a method I have called `OutputMasterFileCsv();` but before doing this I thought I would try out delegates/events for the first time which has led me to a similar result but has also raised a few questions.

**Some background to my application**

This is an Entity Framework Code First MVC web application that is making use of using Unity DI, I have wrapped all my repository calls in an ProcessDataService class in my core layer, which has an interface IProcessDataService that is being registered with Unity.

This is how I have tried to add my event:

**Controller's constructor**

```
public ExceptionsController(IProcessDataService service)
{
    _service = service; //publisher

    //event for delegate         
    OutputService outputService = new OutputService(_service); //subscriber

    _service.LastException += outputService.OnLastException;
}
```

**Output Service**

```
public void OnLastException(object source, EventArgs e)
{
   // output the CSV
}
```

**Process Data Service**

```
public delegate void LastExceptionEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);

    public class ProcessDataService : IProcessDataService
    {        
        private readonly IExceptionRepository _exceptionRepository;        

        public ProcessDataService(IExceptionRepository evpRepo)
        {           
            _exceptionRepository = evpRepo;            
        }

        public event LastExceptionEventHandler LastException;
        public void OnLastException()
        {
            if (LastException != null)
                LastException(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }
```

**New Resolve method in the Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
private ActionResult Resolve(ExceptionViewModel modifiedExceptionViewModel, string currentFilter)
{
      // resolve database records...

        if(_service.WasLastException())
        {
            //raise the event
            _service.OnLastException();
        }

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Exceptions");
}
```

This all works well, however I feel like I am not using delagates and events in the right place here somehow, Instead of calling the `OnLastException()` above and making use of the event, why wouldn't I just simply call `_service.OutputMasterFileCsv();` which is already located in my `ProcessDataService` class?

I believe this has something to do with loose coupling but I dont fully understand what the benefits of this actually are, or am I completely off the mark with all this...?

I thought I would give it ago anyway while I had the chance and hopefully learn something new. If anyone with abit more experience could step in and provide some guidance it would be greatly appreciated as I am a little lost now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are correctly pointing out, using events in this way does not make much sense:

```
if(_service.WasLastException())
{
    //raise the event
    _service.OnLastException();
}
```

You can fix this by making `IProcessDataService` expose a `ResolveException` action, and moving the resolving logic from the controller to the service:

```
[HttpPost]
private ActionResult Resolve(ExceptionViewModel modifiedExceptionViewModel, string currentFilter)
{
    // make needed preparations...

    _service.ResolveException(...prepared parameters...);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Exceptions");
}
```

Then, inside the `ProcessDataService.ResolveException` method check 
if you are currently processing the last exception, and raise the `LastException` event.

```
public class ProcessDataService : IProcessDataService
{    
    //...

    public ResolveException(...prepared parameters...) {
        // resolve an exception and set lastException
        if(lastException) {
            this.OnLastException();
        }
    }

    // notice the private modifier
    private void OnLastException()
    {
        if (LastException != null)
            LastException(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This way the data processing service simply notifies the outside world when the last exception is processed. The service has no idea if anyone cares or does something when this happens. The controller knows even less. Only the output service contains processing logic for last exceptions.

With that said, the real power of events lies in the fact that there can be many subscribers, with each subscriber performing its own tasks without knowing anything about the other subscribers. So, you could for instance add another event handler to say, send an email to a supervisor saying that all the exceptions for the day have been resolved.

What matters is that in this case you would not need to modify the controller or other services to account for this newly introduced email sending functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have decoupled the controller from the service and service from storage. That is fine. But I don't really understand the sense of the event LastException in the ProcessDataService. This is already decoupled by interface IProcessDataService, why to use event?

Another think I don't understand is where is the last exception?

If you want to decouple outputService from ProcessDataService, you can do it like:

```
public ProcessDataService(IExceptionRepository evpRepo, IOutputService outputService)
{           
    _exceptionRepository = evpRepo;  
    _outputService = _outputService;          
}

public void ProcessLastException()
{
    _outputService.Command() //or whatever suitable name you for your method
}
```

And in controller:

```
if(_service.WasLastException())
{
    //call service
    _service.ProcessLastException();
}
```

Or even more simple add some method for processing last exception to IProcessDataService.

There are [more ways how to inject dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You have injected the dependency into constructor and that is why, you don't need the event for decoupling.

Comment: I understand I could just call the method, I mentioned this in my question, I'm just wondering where the ideal place would be to use delegates and events given a similar scenario to my own.